# How can I get Eclipse to warn me about unmappable characters?

Tags: eclipse, utf-8, cross-platform

I recently pasted an ellipsis character (…) into comments in my (Mac) Java code in the Eclipse editor; it compiled fine and complained not at all.  Unfortunately when I checked the code in, the compiler on the (linux) build server was not happy.  How can I configure Eclipse to warn me about such errors?  I saw nothing relevant in Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings.

Answer (score 0):

What encoding is the build server expecting the files to be using? It might not be a case of compiler warnings and errors but of setting the encoding that Eclipse is using to save the files.

**Update**

This one's been bugging me so I ended up searching around for an answer. It would seem that because Eclipse uses its own compiler rather than a stock `javac` you cannot pass arguments to it. There's a `-encoding` option or javac which allows you to specify the encoding of the files to be compiled (without it, the platform default is used).

If the build server is running Linux it's likely defaulting to UTF-8. I know nothing about the Mac's default encoding, but it could be something else entirely. It might be worth creating an ant build task in your project which specifies the character encoding and using that to double check before checking in code. It's a manual process, but might save some pain in the long run.